# Need example of Robolectric with Mockito to write the unit test case

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, mockito, robolectric

How to use with Mocking (Mockito) with Robolectric can any one suggest me and i want to write the unit test cases for an API call also, i try with Robolectric but it only runs the label and actions but for API calls how to write the unit test in Android Test package,Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, I don't think your question is a good match for this site; the question is too broad to be answered here, and it's considered off-topic to find external tutorials or examples. See more about what's on topic at StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Good luck with your testing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't combine Mockito with Robolectric, as far as I understand testing on Android.

You use Robolectric in order to not having to test your **instrumented tests** on emulator or physical device, instead, you test it on **JVM**. That is Robolectric. This allows you also to get access to android framework, and is slower.

Mockito, on the other hand, is a library that allows you to :mock: your dependencies inside a **unit test**. Unit test's purpose is to test the behaviour of the specific software entity, concretely its logic, that you wish to test. Since it don't have access to android framework (it don't need that), it is quite faster.

Edit:

It's actually more complicated. You can have Robolectric together with Mockito (by introducing Mockito rule as a Runner - you have 2 runners then, one @RunWith(AndroidJunit4) - robolectric one, with MockitoRule). And you can just unit test something that needs access to android SDK with Robolectric without actually starting an activity... So these are test configurations I can come up with on Android:

1. (/test) Simple JUnit
2. (/test) **JUnit + Mockito** - classic unit testing in design patterns
3. (/test) **AndroidJUnit (Robolectric) + Mockito without starting activity** - unit testing that requires both android sdk instances and mocking
4. (/test) **AndroidJUnit (Robolectric) - starts activity, you test UI with espresso

   5. (/instrumentedTest) **AndroidJUnit** - the same thing, test ui with espresso

Or you can also have sharedTest. Just one folder for both. With this you can maybe achieve an option to run one test both on device and on VM, I'm just not sure how. Maybe Nitrogen will introduce this option in the future.
https://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/

The ways you can set up your test environment for particular class are many nowadays. I hope that project Nitrogen will simplify this decision making and provide a good documentation on this.

**Edit**

Actually I was wrong when I wrote this comment. You can mock dependencies inside robolectric test. You do that through dependency injection (Koin, Dagger 2) and creating different dependency graph with the same abstractions. (Complicated, check that in some blogs... won't elaborate it here more)

Comment: "and is slower"  AND HOW.

Comment: @Stanislav Kinzl Has Android Nitrogen launched under a different project name as I don't see any mention in the testing documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/testing/

Comment: @AdamHurwitz check this http://newsvideo.su/tech/video/272257 I don't think it launched yet